# Chrome truncates error messages and adds "<omitted>" in window.onerror

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, onerror

We use window.onerror to catch unhandled exceptions (to log them for the dev team, and display a friendly user alert). Recently we noticed that in Google Chrome, the error message got truncated if it was above a certain length, and the text "`...<omitted>...`" was mysteriously added to the error message.

The code below will demonstrate this (in Chrome ver 33.0.1750).  I was wondering if anyone else has had this problem?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        window.onerror = function (errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {
            alert('Error: ' + errorMsg);
        }

        var throwError = function () {
            throw new Error(
            'Something went wrong. Something went wrong. Something went wrong. Something went wrong. ' +
            'Something went wrong. Something went wrong. Something went wrong. Something went wrong. ' + 
            'Something went wrong. Something went wrong. Something went wrong. Something went wrong. ' + 
            'Some text gets truncated before this point!');
        }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <input type="button" onclick="throwError()" value="Throw uncaught error!" /><br /><br />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Argghh, it's drivin' me nuts!

Comment: @masonk - have you tried my answer below, or are you using 3rd party software that you can't edit?

Comment: We have a custom error handler which I'm working on modifying based on your answer. Thanks for it.

Comment: They started limiting error messages to 256 characters ([Source](https://codereview.chromium.org/88393002/patch/1/10001)). I think it's a bad move.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found a solution that works well.

Chrome implements the new HTML standard, in which 2 new parameters have been added to the *onerror* handler, namely: the **colNumber**, and the **error object** (including stack trace).

See:

- https://mikewest.org/2013/08/debugging-runtime-errors-with-window-onerror
- [HTML Living Standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/webappapis.html#errorevent)

The full error message can be accessed through `error.message` as per my code sample below.  This is a duplicate of the 1st parameter `message`, it seems like Chrome has decided to truncate `message`.  Not sure why they had to break something that was working... :-(

IE and FireFox (as of my current versions: 11.0.9600 & 26.0) are not yet implementing the new 5-parameter standard, so the code makes allowance for that.

Hope this helps someone!

**Code sample to return full error message:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    //Chrome passes the error object (5th param) which we must use since it now truncates the Msg (1st param).
    window.onerror = function (errorMsg, url, lineNumber, columnNumber, errorObject) {
        var errMsg;
        //check the errorObject as IE and FF don't pass it through (yet)
        if (errorObject && errorObject !== undefined) {
                errMsg = errorObject.message;
            }
            else {
                errMsg = errorMsg;
            }
        alert('Error: ' + errMsg);
    }

    var throwError = function () {
        throw new Error(
        'Something went wrong. Something went wrong. Something went wrong. Something went wrong. ' +
        'Something went wrong. Something went wrong. Something went wrong. Something went wrong. ' + 
        'Something went wrong. Something went wrong. Something went wrong. Something went wrong. ' + 
        'Text does not get truncated! :-)');
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <input type="button" onclick="throwError()" value="Throw uncaught error!" /><br /><br />
</body>
```

Comment: nice find.  This has been driving us to drink.  Google must own the neighborhood liquor store.

Comment: Sweet, sweet find! You could still do `console.error(errMsg)` instead of the alert though. I hate alerts ;-) And it makes things a **little** more readable.

Comment: i have this script at the top of my angular project, however i don't see it having changed the error output. still getting truncated errors. anyone else have better luck with this? also i noticed that this SO is referred to by the Angular github issue related to this chrome change.

Comment: I'm still getting nothing useful as well. Currently when I get an error it says "Error: Script Error" ... not exactly that helpful. I checked the function and it seems as through chrome isn't even getting an `errorObject`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known problem in Chrome and has already been noticed by other people: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5568.

I don't think there is a workaround, but the bug is already reported: http://crbug.com/331971

Comment: FWIW, this is fixed in version 37, available now via the dev channel.