# How to see what's <omitted> in Chrome debug console

Tags: google-chrome, knockout.js

I am using Knockout.js, and the most important part of the error message is (nowadays) often hidden under the `<omitted>` part. I tried hovering over, and clicking a lot of stuff, but I can't find a way to see the full message. Does anyone have a tip?

Thanks in advance!

PS: I'm looking for a fix **within the Chrome settings**. So without cluttering my code with extra `window.onerror` stuff or otherwise. I don't want to clutter my code just because the Chrome development team thought it was a good idea to omit debug text :S

For a code hack, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22218280/647845

[image]

Comment: Related if not duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199564/chrome-truncates-error-messages-and-adds-omitted-in-window-onerror

Comment: I think that currently this is an open bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=331971 So there is no way the fix this with a simple Chrome setting

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use Firefox. And vote up for this issue in the meantime:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=331971

Answer (score 22):

Here's a little bit of code that will output the whole error message:

```
window.onerror = function (errorMsg, url, lineNumber, columnNumber, errorObject) {
    if (errorObject && /<omitted>/.test(errorMsg)) {
        console.error('Full exception message: ' + errorObject.message);
    }
}
```

You can execute this in the development console in Chrome, so it doesn't have to be in the actual code of your web page.

Comment: Thanks for your workaround, but I rather would people to vote up this issue for the Chromium team. It's really shitty that every knockout/angular developer has to add this extra stuff into their webpages, because they are not fixing this.

Comment: @DirkBoer they have [fixed the issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=331971#c24). It will be back in chrome v37--around the [end of June](http://www.chromium.org/developers/calendar). Until then you can use the canary version of Chrome, this workaround, or a different browser.

Comment: Sounds great! Can't wait for it